# Glassfish and EAR naming conventions

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ear

I have a EAR file that contains a webmodule named foo-web-1.01-SNAPSHOT.war that I deploy in Weblogic and it works fine. When I try the same on Glassfish I get a FileNotFound.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/foo-1.01-SNAPSHOT/foo-web-1_01-SNAPSHOT_war/WEB-INF/web.xml
```

I'm not sure why it's expanded the dots in the filename with underscores. What's the exact specification around this? Is my filename invalid?

EDIT:
My EAR is structure is as follows.

```
foo-1.01-SNAPSHOT.ear
     META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
     META-INF/application.xml
     APP-INF/lib/*.jar
     foo-web-1.01-SNAPSHOT.war
```

The war is structured as follows

```
foo-web-1.01-SNAPSHOT.war
    META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
    WEB-INF/web.xml 
    WEB-INF/webservices.xml
    WEB-INF/wsdl/foo.wsdl
    WEB-INF/lib/*.jar
    WEB-INF/classes/*.class
```

And the application descriptor

```
<application>
  <display-name>foo</display-name>
  <description></description>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>foo-web-1.01-SNAPSHOT.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>/foo</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
</application>
```

Comment: Had exactly the same problem and failed to find an answer. Will be watching this place

Comment: Do you have a `web.xml` in this path? Also it may be helpful if you add information about your deployment structure like `pom.xml` and `application.xml` to the question.

Comment: So what directory do you actually have under applications?

Comment: I've added some information about the EAR structure

Comment: How do you deploy the EAR?

Comment: Either autodeploy or via the console